# Displaying specific set of zip codes (polygons) on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, postal-code, netherlands

For my thesis, I would like to **highlight** the service region of a parcel delivery company in a city in The Netherlands. I recently downloaded QGIS and apart from some tutorials, I don't have a lot of experience. I have a list of coordinates to display the location of parcel receivers, but I would like to also show the boundaries of the ZIP codes where we deliver. Comparable to, let's say, the apps of flash delivery companies (Gorillas, Flink, Getir, Zapp) that show you the area where their couriers deliver groceries.

I found a plugin (PDOK) that has all the Dutch Zip codes, but I just want to display the set where we deliver parcels.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hello dear @jay :) Firstly, I have closed your question, because it was too broad, there were two questions [1] where to find data for Netherlands and [2] how to visualize it. Wonderful, now you are focused, it is about the cartographic visualization of your points in polygons. However, it is not explicit yet, for instance, what have you tried to represent points in polygons, what are your expectation regarding the final output as well as in which format would you like to represent it. I recommend to start with a [choropleth map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) in QGIS.

Comment: If a choropleth map is not what you actually need, then try to create a rule-base symbology for your polygons. Just one rule with a filter `overlay_intersects('point_layer_name')`. And then you will see only polygons that overlap at least one or more points.

Comment: Thanks Taras,
It's actually more specifically about the displaying polygons, showing the points within these polygons is something I will try later. The second suggestion is a good one! I will try to do that and that should work if there are customers in each ZIP code. However, even in case of no points on the map at all, it should display the predetermined set of ZIP codes of the service region.